# When to release AudioRecord object?

Tags: java, android, release, audiorecord

I am using the following code. It works fine and shows the frequency. But everytime before starting the app i need to reinstall it so that it works correctly. Could it be that the object is not getting released? I am including my code here.

```
public class Test extends Activity{

String TAG;
public boolean recording;
AudioRecord recorder;
int numCrossing,p;
short audioData[];
int bufferSize,srate;
TextView disp;
float frequency;
private static int[] sampleRate = new int[] { 44100, 22050, 11025, 8000 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Testing) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(Testing);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    disp = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvDisp);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {

            Log.i(TAG,"Setting up recording");
            for (int rate : sampleRate) {
                try{

                        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate);

            bufferSize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*3; //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

            if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {

            recorder = new AudioRecord (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,rate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder
            srate = rate;
            break;
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
            }
        }


            recording=true; //variable to use start or stop recording
            audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.
            Log.i(TAG,"Got buffer size =" + bufferSize);                
            while (recording) {  //loop while recording is needed
                   Log.i(TAG,"in while 1");
            if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) // check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
            if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
            recorder.startRecording();  //check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.

            else {
                   Log.i(TAG,"in else");
            recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize); //read the PCM audio data into the audioData array

            numCrossing=0; //initialize your number of zero crossings to 0
            for (p=0;p<bufferSize/4;p+=4) {
                   if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+1]>0 && audioData[p+2]<=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+1]<0 && audioData[p+2]>=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+2]>0 && audioData[p+3]<=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+2]<0 && audioData[p+3]>=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+3]>0 && audioData[p+4]<=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p+3]<0 && audioData[p+4]>=0) numCrossing++;
                    }//for p

              for (p=(bufferSize/4)*4;p<bufferSize-1;p++) {
                    if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
                    if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
                    }



            frequency=(srate/bufferSize)*(numCrossing/2);//calculating frequency

             Log.i(TAG, "Calculated Frequency");
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                 public void run()
                 {
                     Log.i(TAG,"In printing statement");
                     disp.setText("The frequency is " + frequency);
                     if(frequency>=15000)
                         recording = false;
                 }
             });


             }//else recorder started


    } //while recording

   if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) 
    recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
    recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
    recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected.
```

}//run

```
    });
    t1.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done an exhaustive reading of your code but I do see that you're setting recording = false only when frequency >= 15000. You're potentially not coming out of your while loop.

BTW... I believe this is what's happening... your thread ties up the recording resources of your device. When you exit the activity, leaving the app, the thread keeps running. When you attempt to start the app again, a new thread is created but the old one is still running and still tying up the recording resources. Reinstalling the app has the effect, I believe, of killing that rogue thread.

Comment: ok.. so i can keep something like a stop button to stop it and set recording=false?

Comment: Yes. What you'll end up doing is setting a variable on your UI (or "main") thread that you then reference in your recording thread. Be aware of synchronization between threads. This is a particularly good tutorial: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c12/s1.html   Section 12.1.3 is particularly applicable.